# How to increase the resolution of ggplots in Rmarkdown html files

Tags: r, r-markdown, cowplot

I am trying to knit an Rmarkdown document which contains a rather large ggplot, that I have created using `cowplot`

This is how one might create such a plot:

```
library(DOSE)
library(cowplot)
library(enrichplot)
data(geneList)
de <- names(geneList)[abs(geneList) > 2]
edo <- enrichDGN(de)
p1 <- dotplot(edo, showCategory=30) + ggtitle("dotplot for ORA")
p2 <- dotplot(edo, showCategory=30) + ggtitle("dotplot for ORA")
p3 <- dotplot(edo, showCategory=30) + ggtitle("dotplot for ORA")

plot_grid(p1,p2,p3, ncol=3)
```

I have added the following parameters in the header of the code chunk of my markdown document:

```
{test echo=F, fig.height=8, fig.width=20, fig.show="hold", fig.align="center"}
```

When I run the code chunk in Rstudio, the resulting image is clear and perfectly readable.
However, when I try to knit it to an html file, it comes out very blurred and barely readable..
Are there any parameters that I should use that I am missing? Increasing `dpi` did not help.

It would also be fine, if the image is wider than the text of the markdown document if that increases quality.

Any help is much appreciated!

Cheers!

Comment: How about adjusting the `fig.retina` parameter?  [See here](http://zevross.com/blog/2017/06/19/tips-and-tricks-for-working-with-images-and-figures-in-r-markdown-documents/#the-fig.retina-argument-is-a-resolution-multiplier) for a discussion.

Comment: When I render the RMD in Viewer it does look a bit blurry. However, when I open it in my browser, even zoomed to 500% it's really clear. Have you looked at it in the browser yet?

Comment: @DaveArmstrong changing the `fig.retina` parameter doesn't help unfortunately.

Comment: @Kat2 Honestly, if I open the HTML in chrome and zoom, the plot doesnt get closer at all. I dont know why this happens. This is how it looks at 500% zoom: https://pasteboard.co/olxnDN3kK0f3.png

Comment: I had the same issue. Setting `fig.retina=3` solved things for me.

Answer (score 0):

if you know you want to knit to html, then you should be using `out.width` and `out.height` using pixels or percentages to specify dimensions. The `fig.width` and `fig.height` are used more so for R-generated images. The `out.width` and `out.height` can be for both R-generated and HTML. Nice explanation here: https://www.zevross.com/blog/2017/06/19/tips-and-tricks-for-working-with-images-and-figures-in-r-markdown-documents/